# javaScript reserved keywords

Tags: javascript, jslint, reserved-words, reserved

I am wondering how JavaScript's reserved keywords / functions are managed.

**Example:**

According to:

> http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

`delete` is a reserved keyword by JavaScript.

Then consider the following snippet for some context:

```
var cookieManager = {
    get: function (name) { 
        // function contents ...
        console.log("cookieManager.get() called");
        return true;
    },
    set: function (name, value, days) {
        // function contents ...
        console.log("cookieManager.set() called");
        return true;
    },
    delete: function (name) { 
        // function contents ...
        console.log("cookieManager.delete() called");
        return true;
    }
};
```

This object has a `delete` property, yet the name of it is reserved by JavaScript so it should fail, right?

Yet when I execute `cookieManager.delete();` in the `webconsole` of `FireFox` I get the following output, suggesting that it works fine:

```
[11:26:00.654] cookieManager.delete();
[11:26:00.656] cookieManager.delete() called
[11:26:00.657] true
```

If, however, you run the code in `JsLint` it says

```
Problem at line 12 character 5: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'delete' (a reserved word).

delete: function (name) {
```

Suggesting that this is a big **no no** approach and should be avoided.

So when should I take reserved keywords into consideration, as in this example it seems to work just like I want it to ( the delete keyword is in the context of the object cookieManager and thus causes no conflicts, hence it can be used ) or should I abide to the bible that is `JsLint` and rename anything that is a reserved keyword by javascript? In this context I could easily rename .delete() to .remove().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually this is allowed as per [ECMAScript specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm). The production rules ([Section 11.1.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5)) for an object literal are:

```
ObjectLiteral :
    {}
    {PropertyNameAndValueList}
    {PropertyNameAndValueList  ,}

PropertyNameAndValueList :
    PropertyAssignment
    PropertyNameAndValueList , PropertyAssignment

PropertyAssignment :
    PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
    get PropertyName ( ){FunctionBody}
    set PropertyName (PropertySetParameterList){FunctionBody}

PropertyName :
    IdentifierName
    StringLiteral
    NumericLiteral
```

In your case, you use an  `IdentifierName` as property name. [Section 7.6.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.6.1) says:

> A reserved word is an `IdentifierName` that cannot be used as an `Identifier`.

Note the difference: You cannot use a reserved keyword as *Identifier*, but as it is a valid *IdentifierName* you can use it as *PropertyName*.

---

Nevertheless, other (versions of) browsers might not tolerate this, so to be on the safe side, I would rename it.

Apart from possible problems with browsers, it might also confuse others who read your code and are not familiar with this rule.

---

FWIW, of course you can always use reserved keywords as strings:

```
var a = {'delete': 'foo'};
alert(a['delete']);
```

Comment: So, to clarify, because the production rule for `PropertyName` uses `IdentifierName` and not `Identifier`, it's fine to use `delete` and so on as a `PropertyName`?

Comment: @Delan: I'd say yes. But that does not mean that browsers follow the same rule.

Comment: Also if you run the code in `"strict mode"` it should throw an error

Comment: Wow +1 for new thing for me :)

Comment: Accepted. Thanks for the updates to your answer as well, they provided some useful information : )