# Is it safe to declare a delete method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So the question is simply, if it's safe (wise) to declare *method* called "delete" in JavaScript. Example:

```js
var request = {
    delete : function (url) {
        // Some code...
    }
}
request.delete('http://page.dev/users/1');
```

I've tested this in Firefox and it's functional, but just wondering if it could cause problems in some other browsers; or in general if is it a good practice.

Comment: Whether it works or not, I'd avoid it just to avoid confusion. I generally stay away from any variable or member which shares a name with a language keyword.

Comment: Will it make a request to the server to delete user 1?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes that's the idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javaScript reserved keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799559/javascript-reserved-keywords)

Comment: and [Browser support for using a reserved word as a property name in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5306315/218196)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll never have an issue if you use `this['style']`, but with `this.style`, you should avoid reserved words, which [does includes delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). According to the spec, it's actually OK to use reserved words as property names, but I would avoid it anyway because there are some bad implementations around (also it just has a generally bad feel to use reserved words, whatever the context).

Comment: Seeing that ES-6 (23.1.3.3) will add `Map.prototype.delete` (and some other `.delete()`s), your "bad feel" should subside a bit ;)

Comment: @nmaier in my book, it's never bad if the *standard itself* uses its own reserved words, otherwise nothing would :P But yeah I see your point. I'd still avoid it in my own code though.

Comment: You can always use `.remove()` or `.erase()`

Comment: Or you can use .destroy()

Comment: Or `.uninsert()`

Answer (score 14):

According to the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6):

> Identifier Names are tokens that are interpreted according to the grammar given in the “Identifiers” section of chapter 5 of the Unicode standard, with some small modifications. An *Identifier* is an *IdentifierName* that is not a *ReservedWord* (see [7.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1)).

This means you cannot use `delete` as a variable or function name, but you can use it as an object property name. This was not the case in the previous version of the specification, which is why most other answers are recommending you avoid using reserved words entirely. However, in ES5-compliant implementations, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not a good idea because delete is a keyword. In the newest versions, they restricted the places where it will cause problems but there still are some.

One way of avoiding any kind of problem would be to use:

```
var request = {
    "delete" : function (url) {
        // Some code...
    }
}
request["delete"]('http://page.dev/users/1');
```

But that's probably a bit less optimized and it's kind of ugly. I'd go with another name such as "remove".

Answer (score 2):

`delete` is in the [JavaScript reserved words list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), use at your own peril.

> delete object.property
>
> delete object['property']

Comment: 2 links to the same resource in 4 seconds! Not sure why yours got downvoted though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use different keyword as other suggested - you can use synonyms like `remove` or `purge` - you get the idea.

But more important - make sure *you're doing server-side validation* for legibility of the call. Otherwise anybody could construct a delete call using "`http://page.dev/users/1`"

Comment: Yes, I could use different name. But if I'd be able to map JS methods to HTTP methods - GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, that would look good. Anyway, I can do something like do_post, do_get, ...

_I do have in mind authorization. No worries._

Comment: Why do you need JS method to have same names as HTTP methods? Look good for who?

Comment: I guess we could perceive it as some form of consistency. jQuery has methods $.post and $.get; anyway, - any better ideas are very welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should note that even using the bracket syntax for accessing properties isn't safe on all browsers.

Internet Explorer 7 and 8 will crash anyway.